# Problems from using two wi-fi adapters?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

So I'm on a computer that I built myself with a bargain bin motherboard. It has a minor issue where the USB slots sometimes glitch out. Since I didn't plan on running my computer over wi-fi, but had to relocate it out of reach of an ethernet cable, I now have a computer running wi-fi with some minor unreliability.

Now, 95% of the time this isn't an issue, as putting the computer to sleep and bringing it back awake fixes whatever the issue is. However, I occasionally do things that can't be interrupted (or, rather, have to be restarted if interrupted), and will get dropped out of Skype or similar programs out of the blue when my adapter dies.

Now, I know that having two adapters won't get me any more speed (unless, of course, the bargain bin backup I put on does something.

First, is this even worth doing? Will a Windows 10 computer switch seamlessly (or, rather, near-seamlessly) when one adapter goes offline?

Second, am I causing trouble for my network by doing this? I don't have a terribly heavy device load: two phones and my computer are the only devices usually on wireless access (though there is another computer that is wired in.

Comment: Your premise has not been substantiated.  Is the USB port intermittent (unlikely), or is the WiFi (which just happens to use USB) intermittent (more likely)?  OTOH having redundant USB WiFI adapters wouldn't help either case IMO.  This is probably an XY question.

Comment: The USB port is intermittent; the front USB's both fail simultaneously (taking my mouse along with the wireless adapter), while rear USB ports tend to fail independently rather than in banks.